# Writing fields to bytecode not working

Tags: java, field, bytecode, dynamic-programming

I am working on writing a class in bytecode but i am confused on how to add fields to the class.  I have tried adding a field like this

```
dout.writeShort(1);
dout.writeShort(Modifier.PUBLIC);
dout.writeShort(stringConstant("hdhd"));
dout.writeShort(stringConstant(classCode(int.class)));
```

but when i try to load the resulting class i get a

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal field modifiers in class test: 0x1
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at BytecodeTest$InterfaceClassLoader.buildInterface(BytecodeTest.java:139)
    at BytecodeTest.main(BytecodeTest.java:25)

I should also mention that the class i am trying to build is an interface.

I dont see what is invalid about the public modifier.

Here is my classCode method

```
private static String classCode(Class<?> c) 
{
    if (c == void.class)
        return "V";
    Class<?> arrayClass = Array.newInstance(c, 0).getClass();
    return arrayClass.getName().substring(1).replace('.', '/');
}
```

---

My problem was that interfaces require final fields and i didn't make the field final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it says you have illegal field flags, you should check the part of the JVM specification regarding field flags. If you had, you would see

> All fields of interfaces must have their ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, and
>   ACC_FINAL flags set; they may have their ACC_SYNTHETIC flag set and
>   must not have any of the other flags in Table 4.19 set

So the solution is to do something like this (not sure of the exact syntax for the library you're using).

```
dout.writeShort(Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL);
```